# Calculate with Integers

Tags: java

So I got to a site where it says Integers don't allow Calculate with it, + - * / % ^ etc.

But I tried

```
Integer n=new Integer(8);
    n+=2;
    Integer m=new Integer(10);
    System.out.println(n+m);
```

and it prints out 20. So I am a little confused. I know this is a noob question but I really want to get this and I don't know what I am missing. So what does this actually mean "integers don't allow calculate with it"

Thanks.

EDIT: @people request :[Site providing accurate information?](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html)

Comment: Can you add a link to site? I am really exited to have a look at it.

Comment: Can you include a reference to the site? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: This works as of Java 1.5 due to boxing/unboxing. This means that you are implicitly converting back and forth between primitive ints and Integer objects. You could also have written `Integer n = 8` and it would compile exactly the same.

Comment: So does this mean that information provided on the site is no longer accurate ?

Comment: I don't know what site you are talking about so I can't know what exactly is claimed there. But it could be that it was written before Java 1.5.

Comment: @Fofole Yes, the site is out of date.  Actually, the site does have a small blurb saying that in Java 1.5 autoboxing will become available.  Since Java 7 has been released (although most people are still using Java 6), your code can assume autoboxing capabilities on any new compiler.

Comment: Now I saw the link, it always takes time after an edit to be visible. Information on that site is crap overall. Get another site to learn from :) For example it makes a mess out of explaining mutable/immutable. Even to talk about the mutability of a primitive value is absurd.

Comment: Well the reason I posted this was because practice thaught me different from what was posted there, so I had my doubts to start with:)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's not absurd to talk about the mutability of a primitive! With the standard SecurityManager you can use reflection to change the underlying value of a boxed Integer, which will the be cached if it's small enough, meaning that 5 can be 27 in all sorts of fun ways! `</tongueInCheek>`

Comment: @yshavit That's what I'm saying -- you are talking about the mutability of a boxed Integer. Now try to say something meaningful about the mutability of a primitive int :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, but autoboxing blurs the line so nicely! I can create a method `int add(Integera0 , Integer a1) { return a0 + a1}` and rig it that `add(5, 3)` returns `30`. Sure looks like I changed some int's value! ;-)

Comment: I agree, nice tricks to fool around with :) Just I wasn't trying to talk about that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, I know. That's why I added the `</tongueInCheek>` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 1.5+ automatically *boxes* (and *unboxes*) primitive types - it's called *autoboxing*.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

The site you encountered may have talked about Java prior 1.5:

> In code prior to Java version [1.4, edited], you had to do a lot of manual tedious converting back and forth from primitive int to Integer Object, and similarly for byte/ Byte, char/Character, short/ Short, long/ Long, float/ Float and double/ Double. (http://mindprod.com/jgloss/autoboxing.html)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to know. It seems the information I found is outdated, thus the confusion. I will accept your answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: Huh? Java 1.1? In all fairness, that page at least gets that right, except for the one blunder you cited :) It's prior to Java 1.5, so it's talking about Java 1.4 or earlier.

Comment: That said, you should still avoid doing arithmetic with `Integer`s whenever possible, just to avoid the overhead of boxing and unboxing. It's doable, it's just best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

That website is probably a bit outdated...

If you were using a Java version prior to 1.4, that statement is true, since you could only use the + operator on primitive types (and Strings... that's a whole other issue).

Currently (read, post Java 1.5), the JVM automagically converts that Integer object to int when you attempt to apply + to it.

Keep in mind that if you try to apply the + operator to an Integer object pointing to null, you *will* get a NullPointerException caused by the unboxing being applied to a null object.

Answer (score -1):

use javascript function `parseInt` for these variables.

[docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Comment: But this question isn't about JavaScript - it's about Java (as is the link you posted).  Also, Java's `Integer.parseInt` converts strings to ints, and this question doesn't involve strings either.